# Compute, for all integers $m,n$, $\int_{|z|=2}z^n(1-z^m)dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

Compute, for all integers $m,n$, $\int_{|z|=2}z^n(1-z^m)dz$.

Isn't $z^n-z^{mn}$ analytic, so the value is 0? And if it isn't analytic, letting $z(t)=2e^{it},t\in[0,2\pi]$ gives
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(2^ne^{nit}-2^{nm}e^{nmit})2ie^{it}dt$$
$$i\int_0^{2\pi}2^{n+1}e^{it(n+1)}-2^{nm+1}e^{it(nm+1)}dt$$
$$=i\bigg[\frac{2^{n+1}}{i(n+1)}e^{it(n+1)}-\frac{2^{nm+1}}{i(nm+1)}e^{it(nm+1)}\bigg]^{2\pi}_0$$
$$=0$$
Is this correct though? This was mean't to be a challenging problem so I doubt the answer would be so trivial.

Comment: What happens to your solution when $n+1$ or $nm+1$ is zero?

Comment: $n$ and or $m$ can be negative.

Comment: But if $n$ is negative the function has a pole at $0$, so it is not analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You need to spilt the cases:

$(1)$ $n<0$ and $m>0$ so you have pole at $z=0$

$(2)$ $n>0$ and $m>0$ so $I=0$

$(3)$ $n<0$ and $m<0$

$(4)$ $n>0$ and $m<0$

I will solve the first and will let you solve $(3)$ and $(4)$ the answer for $(2)$ is zero because the function is analytic

$(1)$ For the first: $n<0$ and $m>0$

$$\int_{|z|=2}z^n(1-z^m)dz$$

Pole at $z=0$

Use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

Let's define $g(z):=1-z^m$

so $$I=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}g^{(n-1)}(z=0)$$

Comment: For case 1, since $n$ is negative, shouldn't it be $I=\frac{2\pi i}{(|n|-1)!}g^{(|n|-1)}(z=0)$?

Comment: If $n$ is negative so it will be in the denominaor, think about it $t^{\color{red}-5}=\frac{1}{t^{\color{red}+5}}$ , in other words when $n$ in the denominator $n$ is positive.

Comment: Since $g(z)=1-z^m$, wouldn't $g^{(n-1)}(0)$ either be 0 or undefined?

Comment: @MattG  this is the derivative $n-1$ times

Comment: yes but $g(z):=1-z^m$, so the $n-1$st derivative at 0 would be 0. I see why it wouldn't be undefined.